# How to hide tax , shipping & handling from cart and checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

## I am using Magento version: 1.9.2.2

I want to hide tax, shipping and handling from cart and checkout page of my app but didn't get any success been trying from last two days.
Followed some solutions(links attached) from the forums and various Websites but not getting any success for this please help to find any solution for this.

## links which I've followed for this:

didn't work:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31603/how-to-remove-tax-from-cart-page,
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54375/how-do-i-remove-total-excl-tax-from-cart-review-page

almost done the trick but **tax** appeared as soon as I logged in https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/63352 ,
Worked for a short period of time **tax** magically reappeared after some time
http://michaelsavin.com/magento-hide-tax-summary-from-cartcheckout/

Answer (score 1):

Open admin panel, go to system > configuration > sales > tax > order, Invoices, Credits Memos display settings 
then set Display full Tax Summery : No